# Hide android soft keyboard in browser

Tags: javascript, android

I'm building a webapp for ios/android and currently got a problem

My app has a input element and when people focus on it, the soft keyboard show as usual.
But some times I want to hide it by javascript, I tried this:

```
document.getElementById('oneinput').blur()
```

It works fine in ios safari , but in android browser, the input element just lost focus but the soft keyboard still appeared.

I also tried to create a click event by javascript on some element but not working either.
Any Ideas?

Comment: have you tried document.activeElement.blur();

Comment: Just tried.. not working either.

Comment: Try this
activeElement.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly'); 
activeElement.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
activeElement.blur();

Comment: @wasaig: Your second suggestion also does not work.